# Why young modulus value doesn't change even if we change the parameters?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, elasticity

The Young modulus of steel is determined using a length of steel wire and is found to have the value EE. Another experiment is carried out using a wire of the same steel, but of half the length and half the diameter.

What value is obtained for the Young modulus in the 2nd experiment?

Why doesn't yhe values change even if we are changing the parameters

Answer (score 3):

Young's modulus is a material property and independent of the size or shape of the specimen being tested

Comment: So does it not depend on ANYTHING?

Comment: It depends on the type of the material, but not on its shape.

Comment: In real situations, Young's modulus does change with temperature. But of course, while solving question it is assumed to be constant.

Answer (score 1):

Young's Modulus is measuring the ratio of **stress** to **strain**.

[Stress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_(mechanics)) is a measure of the forces in a material.  It has units of force ***per unit area***.  This is the reason why changing the diameter does not affect the experiment.  If the wire is thinner you may have to apply a different **force** to get the same strain (elongation/stretching).

The *stress* on the other hand, is the variable we are concerned with, and will depend on both the applied load and the geometry.  We have determined through experiments that many materials have a region where stress is linearly proportional to strain.  The slope of that linear relationship is known as Young's Modulus of elasticity.

Also consider how tension acts when considering what a change in length will do.  In a (ideal) wire, tension is the same through the whole thing.  Because of that; shortening the rope will not change the applied load (but it will change the total length; but not the % elongation).